# React-three-fiber appears to suddenly require a resource that is crashing my application. Security issue or something else?

Tags: reactjs, vite, react-three-fiber

As title mentions app was working perfectly fine. One day I go to check on it and see I this error in the console:

Relevant error 1:
Access to fetch at 'https://market-assets.fra1.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/market-assets/hdris/st-fagans/st_fagans_interior_1k.hdr' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
market-assets.fra1.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/market-assets/hdris/st-fagans/st_fagans_interior_1k.hdr:1

Relevant error 2:
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
2index.js:21 Uncaught Error: Could not load st-fagans/st_fagans_interior_1k.hdr: Failed to fetch)
at Object.onError (index-22ee0173.esm.js:1648:36)
at three.module.js:41524:39

[See here the network initator snippet showing that it's coming from react-three-fiber](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srlR6.png)

I never explicitly request this resource myself, so I'm not sure how I could personally update the cors policy. My application does have a server side that has CORS enabled.

Please let me know what you think this could be and if there is any resolution that glares out to you. Thanks!

Unless I genuinely just blanked, I don't recall having made any changes to the application between it working and having this error so I'm a bit confused on what it could be. Using vite for this project.

Comment: Are you maybe using a [`lobby` environment](https://github.com/pmndrs/drei/blob/master/src/helpers/environment-assets.ts#L6)?

Comment: @AKX wow thanks, changing this to the city preset fixed it....but why haha?

Comment: Ok nevermind...update...it works locally now and there is no request made to get that resource, but when I create the vite dist it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That filename is referred to [here](https://github.com/pmndrs/drei/blob/master/src/helpers/environment-assets.ts#L6) in `drei`'s source as the file for an (HDR) environment named `lobby`.

Something must have changed in the origin server `market-assets.fra1.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com`'s configuration to not serve CORS headers for that file; this apparently [is a known issue with the `drei` folks](https://github.com/pmndrs/drei/pull/1486).

Updating `drei` in your app will probably fix this (since it'll change things to point to another CDN).

Of course, all the better if you host that HDR file locally along with your app, so you're not at the whims of a third party CDN.

Comment: Great find. Thank you sir. Updating drei worked.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, but only on my live app and not on local. Updating to latest /drei carried the issue over to my local.

Finally updating to 9.40.7 fixed the issue for me on local ànd live